# Predicted values from R glm model, while leaving out one term

Tags: r, prediction, glm

I have a glm in R that nicely explains abundance of a species of the form

```
x<-glm(log(abundance) ~ distance+sampling_effort, data=df)
```

All terms are significant (p-value<0.01) and model assumptions seem to be valid. The data is actually from a raster map. Now I want to create predicted values from my model, but while leaving out the `sampling_effort` term. So it would create a new raster map that compensates for sampling effort and thus provides a better prediction of abundance if sampling_effort would be equal everywhere. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some better googling  I found the answer already on http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Remove-term-from-formula-for-predict-lm-td1017686.html

Basically the easiest way is just to set the sampling_effort to 0 in a new dataset and use that with `predict` like this:

```
newdata <- df
newdata$sampling_effort = 0
predicted_values_compensated <- predict(x, newdata)
```